# Is the list of default groups that come with a fresh Ubuntu install documented?

Tags: server, permissions, default, groups

```
adm               _flatpak          list              render            syslog            uucp
audio             floppy            lp                root              systemd-coredump  uuidd
backup            games             mail              rtkit             systemd-journal   video
bin               gnats             man               sasl              systemd-network   voice
cdrom             input             messagebus        sgx               systemd-resolve   webadmin
crontab           irc               shadow            systemd-timesync  www-data          daemon
news              src               tape              dialout           nogroup           _ssh              
tcpdump           dip               operator          staff             tty               disk              
kmem              plugdev           sudo              users             fax               kvm               
proxy             sys               utmp
```

Look at all these groups! I have no idea what most of them even do. Is there documentation for what each group has access to? A lot of them are self explanatory, and I could google them individually, but I would appreciate an online documentation of the groups created by Ubuntu and what they are for. My search for this has turned up fruitless.

Comment: Is it? I'm just asking whether a piece of documentation exists. A fresh install comes with a bunch of groups, and I would assume the list of groups is written down somewhere. I don't expect anybody to know what each individual group is for off the top of their head. I would expect the people who designed the distro to write down how they configured it.

Comment: Archwiki has all of their default groups on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/users_and_groups#Group_list). I would expect Ubuntu to have something similar, but I cannot find it.

Comment: I guess I’ll take that to mean the Ubuntu user groups are undocumented for some reason, because if it were you would’ve shared the documentation  instead of the forum’s content policy.